# PHP Firebird connection error: connection rejected by remote interface - how can I fix this?

Tags: php, pdo, firebird

I am trying to connect to a Firebird 1.5 instance from a PHP 5.6 installation and I am getting the following error:

> Connection attempt failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [335544421] connection
> rejected by remote interface

I know the Firebird version is old and I should update it, but it is just not possible at the moment.

I've already gone through some tips saying that I should tag "wireCrypt = Disabled" in firebird.conf, but that is not an option since I am using Firebird 1.5.

Ive already checked my firewall to allow connections to port 3050.
Other computer on the same network are able to access the database with no problems. The problem only happens when I try to access it through PHP

The code I am using to try to connect to the Firebird database is the following:

```php
<?PHP
$str_conn="firebird;dbname=localhost/3050:/pathToMyDatabase.fdb;charset=UTF8";
$conn = new PDO($str_conn, "SYSDBA", "masterkey");
?>
```

Comment: Provide your code, please. How could we help you if we even don't realize how are you trying to connect?

Comment: Sorry for that. Just updated the question with the code I am using

Comment: Is your PHP server running on the same host as the DB? Since you mentioned firewalls, it seems that might not be the case. Are you sure `localhost` is the right host?

Comment: yeah, everything is running on my machine. Php 5.6 and Firebird 1.5 on a CentOS 7 machine

Comment: Have you checked the firebird.log of the server **and** the client (they might share the same file or have their own)? It might contain information about what is wrong. In any case, both your Firebird version and your PHP version are so ancient, you're lucky they run at all... The error itself basically means that the Firebird client and Firebird server could not agree on connection options, but I can't readily think of that happening with Firebird 1.5.

Comment: yeah yeah, I do believe that's because of the version of everything. it works on an ancient machine. CentOS 6, firebird 1.5 and PHP 5.6, But I strongly believe they did some sort of magic to get that working.
I will try reading the logs and get back to you.

Comment: Perhaps, they run Firebird server...

Comment: what do you mean, @user13964273?

Comment: "Connection rejected by remote interface" is one of possible errors in the case when there is no TCP listener on target host for given port. I.e. Firebird server is not run.

Comment: @user13964273 That would result in a _"Unable to complete network request to host "localhost"."_ error (isc_network_error), not in a isc_connect_reject.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel You are right. I mixed up Firebird's "connection rejected by remote interface" and Winsock's "connection refused" messages, sorry.

Comment: well, I checked everything you guys suggested and yet, no progress. I do agree that's because of some sort of mismatch between the version of my PDO Firebird lib and the Firebird server version I am trying to connect to. Unfortunately everything is so old and I am not sure which version I should use nor where to find such legacy dependencies...

Comment: Guys, I got it!!!

After researching like hell all over the internet, the answer was a bit more trick. Well, back to hardware mode and rather than using YUM INSTALL... I decided to compile everything I need and BAANG it worked.

this link over here gave me a clue: https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/third_party_docs/Firebird_DreamWeaver_PHP_Phakt.pdf

after that I just remove everything, downloaded PHP and Apache, COMPILE, MAKE, MAKE INSTALL like it is supposed to and now I am working to connect everything I need.

And hell yeah I will define a strategy for migrating everything.